# Is there any way that i can use button click event via shiny GUI to call a R Script?

Tags: r, event-handling, shiny

I am trying to develop my GUI in Shiny. I have made R Scripts. I want to call the R Script via button click event (run the R Script when i click on the button)

Comment: Why not just embed R code into the shiny app and call the result natively (in whichever form is available)?

Comment: Why not source() them?

Comment: I don't know.. Shiny is using entirely different code. I can't understand to connect it.

Comment: Shiny is a library that has its own functions, I think you should go and read everything here http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/ before jumping into it

Comment: @pops I kw shiny is a library. Just to let u kw I have already read those tutorials. There's nowhere written in those videos how to connect shiny with R Scripts. or event handling in shiny to call r Script. I have got to know to connect R Scripts with VB.NET and other external programming language. but i m looking for solution in R only.

Comment: Can you please clearly explain what you want to connect to what and how. And what is it you are actually doing. Konrad gave you examples how to call R scripts with source() already. If you want to call R and Rshiny from other languages I am sure you can find examples online. like this one http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/340241/Integration-R-into-VB-NET-applications

As you can see your question doesn't make too much sense hence it has been put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you will be interested in developing a set of *global* objects. In Shiny's terminology:

> Objects defined in `global.R` are similar to those defined in `server.R`
>   outside shinyServer(), with one important difference: they are also
>   visible to the code in `ui.R`. This is because they are loaded into the
>   global environment of the R session; all R code in a Shiny app is run
>   in the global environment or a child of it.

As discussed [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html). Further on similar lines, you can source your scripts to Shiny:

```
# Objects in this file are shared across all sessions
source('all_sessions.R', local=TRUE)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  # Objects in this file are defined in each session
  source('each_session.R', local=TRUE)

  output$text <- renderText({
    # Objects in this file are defined each time this function is called
    source('each_call.R', local=TRUE)

    # ...
  })
})
```

I would suggest that you have a look at the [linked article](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html) where the matter of sourcing code outside `server.R` and `ui.R` is discussed in detail.